# Trying to write CSS

Tags: selenium

I am trying to write CSS using two attributes the element looks like this:

```
<div class="bet-tab-left bet-tab tab-event bet-tab-half bet-tab-last-tab active" data-tab-index="1">
```

How do I write CSS element locator by.css("x") for this?

Comment: Did you try my answer? If it helpful -- check a tick near my answer, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per the `HTML` you have shared, you can use the `class` attributes to identify the `WebElement` as follows :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.bet-tab-left.bet-tab.tab-event.bet-tab-half.bet-tab-last-tab.active"));
```

Still if you want to use both the `class` and `data-tab-index` attributes, you can use:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='bet-tab-left bet-tab tab-event bet-tab-half bet-tab-last-tab active'][data-tab-index='1']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this using `data-tab-index="1"`:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-tab-index=1]"));
```